# Localizing "ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender"

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am using `ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender` in my multi lingual project.
The problem with this calender is that it localizes the month strings in the control but doesn't localize the Today string and i need to localize this text also.

Please anyone help me out in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
protected void CalendarExtender1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CalendarExtender1.TodaysDateFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
        // or
        //CalendarExtender1.TodaysDateFormat = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern;

    }
```

Comment: i am usung ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender, i don't have TodaysDateFormat  property in this control.

Comment: which version of toolkit are you using? 
code which i have done is using version 3.0.30930.0

Comment: thanks dotnetexperiments for help , actually i want to localize the text "Today" in the calender control not the format....Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: I don't understand why his is marked as the answer, just as Bovi_Khurja says in the comments, this does not answer the question about the "Today" string.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the ScriptManager.EnableScriptGlobalization property to True. It should work as long as you are setting the desired cutlture value.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Lang = “es-MX”;//set your culture here
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
        new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Lang);
}
```